# Closest line to a point using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table of roads and a table of points. I'd like for each point to have the ID of the closest road, as well as the distance to that road.

The line data has both the path type and the geometry type for its coordinates. The points have XY coordinates. What would be the best way to go about finding the closest road using PostGIS?

Comment: Do you have a threshold distance such that points greater than the threshold distance from a road are assigned a null ID?

Comment: Hmm, probably something like 100 feet?

Comment: Did you try this? http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html

Comment: I haven't seen this. Checking it out now.

Comment: Try this as well: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor

Comment: And another one, slightly more up to date, as uses lateral join. https://carto.com/blog/lateral-joins/

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in the point XY to [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to return the ID of the closest road, as well as the distance to that road:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) p.id, r.id, ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_Makepoint(p.x, p.y),4326), r.geom)
FROM points p
    LEFT JOIN roads r ON ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(ST_Makepoint(p.x, p.y),4326), r.geom, 30.48)
ORDER BY p.id, ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_Makepoint(p.x, p.y),4326), r.geom);
```